# How can I use two different public keys with the same private key for fully homomorphic encryption?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, proxy-re-encryption

I am pretty new to cryptography.

Recently I run into this question where I have two different public keys with the same private key, and I need them for fully homomorphic encryption.

Let's say messages from party $A$ and party $B$ are encrypted by two different public keys and FHE operations are performed on the encrypted messages. Party $C$ having his own private key wants to decrypt it. Before the FHE, the two messages are re-encrypted under $C$'s private key.

How do I perform the FHE operations on these two messages encrypted by different public keys?

P.S. I am using the Palisade library to implement my idea. A little suggestion on how to implement this on Palisade would also be really appreciated.

Comment: Update: I found one solution in this survey paper(https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.09270.pdf). So in section 5.2, MKHE basically concatenates the keys to have a final key. It seems to meet my goal here but I am still trying to implement this. Not sure if it works or not and there might be a better solution out there.

Comment: Forgot to update. I realized later that the answer is actually straightforward. After both messages are re-encrypted under $C$'s private key, then they can be used in the same FHE function. This is because the re-encryption basically changes the message to be under the same scheme.